# Alternative to COBYLA.optimize in algorithms.optimizers

Tags: qiskit

I was working on [this](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/vqe-molecules.html) qiskit tutorial, regarding simulation of VQE. In one of the code blocks they did this:

```
from qiskit.aqua.components.optimizers import COBYLA
```

Now I know that aqua is deprecated and the new way is to

```
from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import COBYLA
```

But now in the further down, they used COBYLA.optimize, which was only available in the aqua version, there is no optimize in algorithms version.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new version of the book has the updated chapter, without Aqua: https://learn.qiskit.org/course/ch-applications/simulating-molecules-using-vqe

Basically, the main change is that `COBYLA.optimize` is `COBYLA.minimize` now.

Comment: I reported the problem and upload the fix here https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-textbook/pull/1494